# DNN Password change/reset doesn't accept "%" symbol

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

My DNN version is 07.02.00, and when I want to change/reset a password that contains the symbol "%" I get this error:

```
Failed to update password - either the username/token combination is invalid (or the token has expired), or the password is not valid. Passwords must be at least 7 characters in length and contain at least 0 non-alphanumeric characters.
```

I tried to resolve this by using that regex (didn't work):

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" **passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^.*(?=.{6,}).*$"** connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if my solution is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usualy happens when you try to change your password and it's similar to the old one and it doesn't anything have to do with the symbol "%".